# RegEx to match 4 minus non-adjacent

Tags: regex

Is there any way to create a RegEx matching `*-*-*-*-*` (a string with 4 ", so it would match `1-2-3-4-5`, `AB-CD-EF-GH-IJ` but not `9-8-7`?

Closest RegEx I have tried is `([\w\-\.]+[\-\.][\w\-\.]+[\w\-\.]+)` but it matches 9-8-7, too.

Comment: Match word which contains at least 4 non-adjacent `-` sign ?

Comment: [`(\w+(?:-\w+){4})`](https://regex101.com/r/iU2oU7/1)

Answer (score 1):

With no other constraints, `-([^-]+-){3}` matches your requirement.

Your own attempt only covered three repetitions, and would allow a period or whitespace instead of any of the dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this `^(?:[^-]+\-){4}[^-]+$`

(any character other than `-` one or more time followed by a dash) 4 times, then any other character one or more times

Comment: This will also match `A-B-C-D--`?

Comment: Thanks! `([^\-]+\-){4}[^\-]+` does it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `([^-])+-([^-])+-([^-])+-([^-])+-([^-])+`. `([^-])+` will match every string that doesn't have `-` in it.

Comment: Or a backslash, the way you wrote it.

Comment: I used backslash to escape the `-`.

Comment: That's not what it does. There is no need to escape the minus, as long as it's first or last in the character class, nor is there any way to. In a character class, a backslash just stands for itself, in most regex dialects.

Comment: Trying with and without escaping on online regex tools gives the same result, but I agree removing the escaping makes it far more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*([^-]|^)-){4}
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/jL9nY2/1)

- `.*` - zero or more characters
- `([^-]|^)` - a character, which is not a dash or the beginning of the string itself
- `-` - a dash literally
- `{4}` - the whole thing repeated 4 times

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^[^-.]+([-.])(?:[^-.]+\1){3}[^-.]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uL1hI2/1)

**Breakup:**

```
^            # start
[^-.]+       # match 1 or more of non-dot & non-hyphen char
([-.])       # match 1 dot OR hyphen char and capture it as group #1
(?:          # non-capturing group start
   [^-.]+    # match 1 or more of non-dot & non-hyphen char
   \1        # match same char as captured in group #1
){3}         # non-capturing group end, repeat 3 occurrences of this group
[^-.]+       # match 1 or more of non-dot & non-hyphen char
$            # end
```

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, if you set X to mean 'any character except non-adjacent hyphens', then you pattern becomes

`X*-X+-X+-X+-X*`

So the challenge is just defining X as all non-hyphens or strings of adjacent hyphens.

`([^-]|(--+))`

Composing the two...

`([^-]|(--+))*-([^-]|(--+))+-([^-]|(--+))+-([^-]|(--+))+-([^-]|(--+))*`

Try it here...
https://regex101.com/r/lG3hM5/1